# Video with audio recording compatible with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, audio, html5-video

I have been searching web for Video with Audio recording in browser, which should be compatible with at least major browser mainly `internet explore`. 
I know about `WebRTC` but it only support in `Chrome`. I want to find the solution for `Internet Explore`. I have google lot more but not found anything which will point me to right direction. I know `Flash` can be supported in IE but not found any good resource how to record video with audio using `Flash`. Any suggestion would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to save the video locally or on a server?
You can store a webcam video on a server. But you need a Media Server. (Flash Media Server - but it costs a lot) or RED5, its FREE: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server

Then you have to open a connection:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(RED5_PATH);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

var cam:Camera = Camera.get();
var micro:Microphone = Microphone.get();
ns.setBufferTime(100); 
ns.attachVideo(cam);
ns.attachAudio(micro);
```